# SQL transpose without column for labels

Tags: sql

I'm a beginner and am having some difficulty transposing - think it may be a conceptual gap so any help would be much appreciated.

I'm querying a table that contains appointment booking information within Metabase in order to output a table with 6 rows and 2 columns.

Metabase needs the following format to visualize the data in a funnel:

| Stage | Count | Conversion % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Booked 1st Apt | 100 | 100% |
| Booked 2nd Apt | 80 | 80% |
| Booked 3rd Apt | 40 | 40% |
| Booked 4th Apt | 4 | 4% |

But right now I only have the stage and count, without any labels, and the rows/columns are switched.

My output looks like:

| Booked 1st Apt | Booked 2nd Apt | Booked 3rd Apt | Booked 4th Apt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 80 | 40 | 4 |

How do I get things in the right format (transposing rows and columns)? Do I need to add a column that gives the labels of the data first? Is my output not actually a table? Sorry for so many questions, am teaching myself SQL!

Pasting my code below.. not positive how to get it in the right format so apologies if it's off!:

```
WITH apts (patient_id, Apt_Booked, Comp_Apts1, NPS_answer)
AS

(select
    patient_id,
    count(patient_id) AS Appointment_Booked,
    SUM(case
        WHEN canceled_at IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END) 
        AS Completed_Appointments,
        
    NPS_answer

from Appointments

GROUP BY patient_id, nps_answer),

finaltable (Booked_First_Appointment, Completed_Second_Appointment, Completed_Third_appointment, Completed_Fourth_Appointment, Completed_Fifth_Appointment) AS

(Select 

        SUM(CASE WHEN Apt_Booked > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Booked_First_Appointment,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Comp_Apts1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed_First_Appointment,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Comp_Apts1 > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed_Second_Appointment,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Comp_Apts1 > 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed_Third_Appointment,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Comp_Apts1 > 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed_Fourth_Appointment,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Comp_Apts1 > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Completed_Fifth_Appointment
        --CASE WHEN Comp_Apts1 > 1 AND NPS_answer > 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS NPS_Promoter

FROM apts)

SELECT *

FROM
    finaltable;
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PIVOT like this situations. Pivot always fast and right solution.

This is a manuel version. if you need dynamic columns for ur query i can do it for you.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (Stage varchar(50), Count int, Conversion int)

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('Booked 1st Apt',100,100),('Booked 2nd Apt',80,80),('Booked 3rd Apt',40,40),('Booked 4th Apt',4,4)

-- static method
SELECT SUM(Pvt.[Booked 1st Apt]) as [Booked 1st Apt],
SUM(Pvt.[Booked 2nd Apt]) as [Booked 2nd Apt],
SUM(Pvt.[Booked 3rd Apt]) as [Booked 3rd Apt],
SUM(Pvt.[Booked 4th Apt]) as [Booked 4th Apt]
FROM @table as T
PIVOT (
    SUM(Count) FOR Stage IN (
        [Booked 1st Apt],
        [Booked 2nd Apt],
        [Booked 3rd Apt],
        [Booked 4th Apt]
    )
) as Pvt
```

Result

| Booked 1st Apt | Booked 2nd Apt | Booked 3rd Apt | Booked 4th Apt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 80 | 40 | 4 |

Comment: Would I be able to union the results instead?